# ThinkingSphinx, search_for_ids returns limited ids array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have noticed in Rails console that
`Model.search_for_ids.size != Model.all.size`

Moreover Thinking Shpinx method `search_for_ids` returns maximum 20 entries.

Any idea how to set unlimited entries for `search_for_ids`?

`:per_page` works but in my opinion, it's ugly to write code like that

`Model.search_for_ids :with => conditions, :per_page => 1294967294`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ThinkingSphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html), "Sphinx paginates search results by default. Indeed, there’s no way to turn it off (but you can request really big pages should you wish)"

Comment: Exactly - this is Sphinx's behaviour, not Thinking Sphinx.